# Creating New MIPS Instruction

Tags: c, assembly, mips, instruction-set, machine-code

I'm having some problems understanding a question. Consider a proposed new instruction named rpt. This instruction combines a loop’s condition check and counter decrement into a single instruction. For example, `rpt $s0, loop` would do the following:

```
if (x29 > 0) {
   x29 = x29 − 1;
   goto loop
}
```

1. If this instruction were to be implemented in the MIPS instruction set, what is the most appropriate instruction format?
   I suppose the J-format would do? (that is, 6 bits of op & 26 bits of address) Since the instruction would have to jump to `loop`, you would need a large field to fit the address. However there is a parameter `$s0`, I'm very confused what it is used for and also the `x29`.
2. What is the shortest sequence of MIPS instructions that performs the same operation?

Can someone give me a clear explanation of what this rpt instruction and loop does and answer the two questions? I would gladly appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a problem you'll have to resolve:

The assembly example uses `$s0`, which is register 16.  But the description of the operation uses x29, which could refer to the stack pointer register, $29, but certainly not `$s0`.  So, these two don't match up and until you get them to match up, you'll have troubles.

By contrast, the usage of `loop` in the operational description seems to match up with the usage of label `loop` in the assembly form.

How it would look if it matched up:

A:

```
rpt $s0, loop
---
if ($s0 > 0) {
   $s0 = $s0 − 1;
   goto loop
}
```

This matches up because `$s0` and `loop` are in both the assembly form and the operational description.

Resolving this way, a J-Type instruction would not accommodate encoding both the register and instruction target.

or else B:

```
rpt loop
---
if (x29 > 0) {
   x29 = x29 − 1;
   goto loop
}
```

This matches up because `x29` is used in the operational description; it is simply implied in the assembly syntax — i.e it is hard coded to 29 and the assembly programmer cannot specify a different register.

Resolving this way, a J-Type instruction might be applicable, since only an instruction target need be encoded.

---

Further confusing things is that the xN register notation is not typical of MIPS, but of ARM and RISC V processors.  MIPS assembly would use the `$29` notation instead.  So, that piece seems out of context.

My suspicion is that someone did an bad/incomplete job of translating this problem from RISC V (where `x29`, aka `t4`, is a reasonable register to used) to MIPS.

Suggest you take this back to your instructors and clarify.